# Access VBA Import Specific Excel Files from different subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, datatables

I have a problem that I can't find the right code to do it.

So I have a Main Folder (C:\Products) with multiple subfolders that correspond to different the products (C:\Products\Chocolates , C:\Products\Milk and many more). 
Each subfolder have many excel files but I just want to import the one that is named sells.xlxs. Each subfolder have a sells.xlxs and I Want to import all sells.xlxs to an access Database.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't Upload the code I was using:

```
Sub Insert2()
  Const cstrSheetName As String = "Weekly"
  Dim strDir As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strTableName As String
  Dim MyPath As String
  Dim i As Long

  i = 0
   MyPath = "C:\Products"
   strTableName = "Sells"
  If Left(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
   strDir = MyPath & "\"
  Else
   strDir = MyPath
 End If
   strFile = Dir(MyPath & "\Sells.XLSX")
While strFile <> ""
 i = i + 1
 strFile = strDir & strFile
 Debug.Print "importing " & strFile

     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    TransferType:=acImport, _
    SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
     TableName:=strTableName, _
    FileName:=strFile, _
    HasFieldNames:=True, _
    Range:=cstrSheetName & "$"

  strFile = Dir()

 Wend
  End Sub
```

Do you think you can help me?

Many thanks

Comment: This site is not about finding other programmers to do the work for you. Taken from the http://stackoverflow.com/tour -> "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." (...) "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: You're are right. I totally forgot of putting the code I was using. I already update

Comment: There are plenty of threads where you can get examples of recursively drill down directories here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

HostFolder = MyPath

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        Dim File
        For Each File In Folder.Files
            ' Operate on each file
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Code credit to [Rich,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031929/rich) rearranged code so it doesn't recursively iterate all subfolders, just the subfolders of `MyPath`